# continuity of function and its domain

Tags: limits

I have two questions.

1. The function 
   $$f(x) =  x^2 \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$$

is continuous at $x=0$, however, [wolfram claims](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2(sin(1%2Fx)) that its domain is $R-\{0\}$. Why is that?

2.The function $\tan(\theta)$ is continuous in spite of not being defined at $\pi/2$. Is it because $\pi/2$ is not part of it's domain?

Comment: My guess is that wolfram just looks at that $1/x$ and says, nope, not defined at zero.

Answer (score 3):

1. The function $f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$ have a right and a left limit when $x\to 0$, so it can be extended by continuity on $0$.

(You can prove that by noticing that $\sin(x)\underset{x\to 0}{\sim}x$.)

You will then have a function define on $\mathbb R$:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin\left(\frac 1x\right) &\text{ for $x\ne 0$} \\ 0 &\text{ for $x=0$} \end{cases}$$

which is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

However, the initial function is not defined for $x=0$.

2. You're right, the function $\tan$ is not defined on $\mathbb R$, and it is continuous where it is defined (it is a nonsense to look for continuity where it is not even defined).

Comment: I am sorry, I mentioned the wrong function in my question (the link was correct). Kindly update your answer!

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer.

Comment: Why is the initial function not defined at `x=0`, isn't it just `0 * {value b/w 1 and 0}`?

Comment: It is not defined at $x=0$, because $1/0$ is not defined. You could look at a simpler function like $g(x)=x/x$, which you can obviously extend at $x=0$, though $g$ is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: But we know for sure that whatever happens, `sin` will always be `-1<=sin(x)<=1`. Then it boils down to `0 * {value b/w 1 and 0}`. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not really missing anything. Your argument shows indeed that $f$ can be extended to a continuous function by adding the condition $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$. Though, without any extension, the function is not defined at $x=0$ (even if you know what "should" be the value at $x=0$, that's not the point !). May be someone wants to say $f(x)=\pi$, which won't make the function continuous, but it is a legit choice anyway.